# Two date find between two data in collection

Tags: mongodb

I have below collection data in mongo db.
    "enddate" : ISODate("2019-03-27T14:30:00.000Z"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-03-27T10:30:00.000Z"),

I have two date like start date "2019-03-26T19:30:00.000Z" and end date "2019-03-26T20:30:00.000Z"

I want to find above two date time period exits in collection or not.
Please help to make mongodb query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
advt.date = m.utc().toISOString();
advt.enddate = me.utc().toISOString();
advt.time = m.utc().toISOString();
advt.endtime = me.utc().toISOString();                                


var Query = Advertisement.find({
                                    $or: [ 
                                        { $and:[{ date: { $gte: advt.date }, enddate:{ $lte: advt.enddate } }] } , 
                                        { $and:[{ enddate: { $gte: advt.date }, date:{ $lte: advt.enddate } }] } 
                                    ],"ad_type":"splash", "isDeleted":false, "_id":{ $ne: advt._id }  
                                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObjectId.getTimestamp()` for that purpose.

Also check this [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/)